# jQuery Autocomplete "TypeError: callback is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I try to write jQuery script with autocomplete, and select correct value on the client side.

My working code without selected value (it give me all username available in my json):

```
$(function() {
        $( "#users" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1/json.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.employee, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.username,
                            };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event,ui) {
                $('#users').val(ui.item.username);
            }
        });
```

But when I try to add selector, how in [this](http://www.jensbits.com/2011/04/28/jquery-ui-autocomplete-search-from-beginning-of-string/) example.

My code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#users" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/json.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                    var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
                    var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
                    response($.grep($.map(data.employee, function(item){
                        return {
                            label: matcher.test(item.username),
                        }
                    })));
                }
            });
        },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event,ui) {
            $('#users').val(ui.item.username);
        }
    });
});
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: callback is not a function  jquery-1.10.2.js:762

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. my json:

> {"employee":[{"username":"username1","placeId":"505B-D","subordinates":["username2","username3"]},{"username":"username4","placeId":"505B-A","subordinates":["username5","username6"]}]}

Comment: You're not passing a function to `$.grep`.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `$.grep`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use grep and map together, you can write something like this:

```
function() {
        $( "#users" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://172.18.128.186/json.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
                        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
                        var g = $.grep(data, function(item){return matcher.test(item.username);});
                        response($.map(g, function(item){return {label: item.username,}}));
                    }
                });
            },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event,ui) {
                $('#users').val(ui.item.username);
            }
        });
```